# Removing the bottom border from the active tab

Tags: css

How can the html code be modified below so as to get rid or hide the bottom border from the active and/or selected tab? I can't seem to figure this out and it doesn't make any sense to me.

```
<style type="text/css">
      ul#tabs { list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0.3em 0; }
      ul#tabs li { display: inline; }
      ul#tabs li a { color: #42454a; background-color: #dedbde; border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; border-bottom: none; padding: 0.3em; text-decoration: none; }
      ul#tabs li a:hover { background-color: #f1f0ee; }
      ul#tabs li a.selected { color: #000; background-color: #f1f0ee; font-weight: bold; padding: 0.3em 0.3em 0.38em 0.3em; }
      div.tabContent { width: 1000px; border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #f1f0ee; }
      div.tabContent.hide { display: none; }
    </style>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EnfxC/

Comment: Can you show us your html as well?

Comment: which bottom border you want to hide? can you as well show part where the tab is already selected.

Comment: There's no active tab in that demo. It's hard to know what you'd like fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the bottom border, then you can write the code in css: (add another class for this)
bottom-border:none !important;

Please tell me the html code...then i could help you